# Update Latte Dock v0.9 to v0.10

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma, plasma5

I am starting to use Arch Linux and, I am customizing my KDE Plasma.
I've initially installed Latte Dock 0.9 because I thought it was the latest version.
Now I need the Latte Dock 0.10 because, with the Latte Dock 0.9, tapplet-latte-sidebar-button breaks.

Can anyone help me?
I didn't find anything that could help me and, because I already have Latte Dock 0.9 installed, I don't know how to do it.

Sorry if it's a simple question or if the solution is simple. I am starting to use Linux as my main operating system and, I don't want to break something.

**Edit:**

To install it, I've cloned these [repository](https://github.com/KDE/latte-dock).

Then I've run these two commands.

```
sudo pacman -Syu
sudo pacman -S cmake extra-cmake-modules python plasma-framework plasma-desktop
```

After I run the installation script

```
sh install.sh
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! It'd help if you could edit your question and include how you installed it in the first place

Comment: @Panki I've edited the question with the steps that I followed to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've unistalled with pacman and installed using yay, for some reason using yay it worked and installed the v0.10